# HtmlUnit, how to check if every asset was loaded?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for integration-testing.

In HtmlUnit, there is [WebResponse::getStatusCode()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebResponse.html#getStatusCode) for accessing `HTTP_STATUS_CODE` of currently loaded page. Let's say, my [Page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/Page.html) is "about" google.com, statusCode will be 200, usually.

I am wondering, if it is possible with HtmlUnit to check, if all required assets (*.css, *.js) were loaded successfully (200 <= statusCode < [300|400]).

In my use case, my tested page works fine - but a .css-file is missing, so the layout is broken. I would like to assert in my test-case, that each required assert can be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept all communication and store information about all assets.

Something like:

```
new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

    public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
        WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);

        URL url = request.getUrl();
        int status = response.getStatusCode();
        // store the status

        return response;
    }
};
```

Comment: n1 idea! Im gonna have a look